# TSC printer QRCODE command converts comma into 0 automatically

Tags: asp.net, printing, qr-code, thermal-printer, tspl

I have TSC TA210 printer and integrating it with my portal built in ASP.NET core.

QRCODE is working fine but when i write comma (,) in text , it automatically converts it into 0.

> Example:

```
TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("QRCODE 40,320,M,4,M,0,M2,\"name:abcd , surname:pqrs\"");
```

This line generates QR code and when i read that code using qr code scanner i get text like this

> name:abcd 0 surname:pqrs

So basically how can i use characters like , and & in tsc printer code.

Comment: Please try changing the encoding mode specification from `M` to `A`. For example, try changing the part of `40,320, M, 4, M, 0, M2,` to `40,320, M, 4, A, 0, M2,`. [TSPL/TSPL2 Programming Language](https://www.tscprinters.com/EN/DownloadFile/readpdf/support/4356/TSPL_TSPL2_Programming.pdf) page 65-66(On the printed footer)

Comment: I really dont know why i didnt think of that !
This worked for me . Thnx !!

Comment: @parthrajpanchal i need some help in setting up the tsc ta210 can you inbox me please. tsclib.dll saying driver not specified.